# javascript, unrecognized character with spread operator inside reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am building a little function and seem to be having an issue with the spread operator. My linter is yelling at me about a spread operator, but I have no issue with using it elsewhere in my app. I have been starting at this and cannot for the life of me figure out why. Here is the function :

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props) {
return actionCreators.reduce(function(memo, value, key) {
    return {...memo,
        [key]: value.bind(null, dispatch)
    };
}, {});
}
```

it's pointing to the second . in the spread operator and saying unrecognized character. I believe I have something syntactically incorrect but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you post the error you get? Also bear in mind that the spread operator for destructuring is not yet supported by most browsers.

Comment: The SpreadProperty is not part of ES6. It is a proposal for ES2017. Your linter probably doesn't know of this proposal yet.

Comment: I would also log out  `memo` and make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: The spread operator works in my code (I am using it in an above part of the code just fine).

Answer (score 1):

Spread properties are not part of ES6. [It is a proposal for ES20XX](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread). Your linter probably doesn't know of this proposal yet.

You need to configure your linter to use a parser that understands this syntax or use a different linter that allows you to do that, such as http://eslint.org/ .

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified more, the spread operator works in my code (I am using it in other locations).

Comment: Are you saying the linter does not complain in these other cases?

Comment: Yes, and thank you for your help! I just used some lodash methods to get around it for now... I'm really not sure what the issue is

Comment: The issue is that the linter is correctly pointing out that your syntax isn't part of javascript.  You might have something like Babel which will translate it into valid code and thus make it work for you, but your linter doesn't know about that. It just knows that you're using a syntax that isn't a standard or supported in a browser.  You might be able to find an "allow experimental" configuration option for your linter to accept it as valid syntax.